# Hover an I tag change the font icon inside it and before it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code:

```
<div class="rate-instructors">
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</div>

<div class="rate-activities">
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</div>
```

I wanted to change it to `fa fa-star-o`, for example I hovered the 3rd `i` in rate-instructors, I wanted it and the first 2 to be in `fa fa-star-o` only in `div` with class `rate-instructors`. Is it possible?

My tried code:

```
 $('i').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('class','fa fa-star-o');
 });
```

Comment: Yes, this is definitely possible. If you have issues in making this work, please add your JS code to the question so we can help you debug it.

Comment: Can you give me a working code? I am having a hard time with this

Comment: Sorry, no. SO is not a code-writing service. As I said above, if you edit the question to include the non-working code that you have we will happily help you debug it.

Comment: Okay i forgot! lol

Comment: `Is it possible` - Have you tried doing it and failed? or Have you not even started? In any case...You will have to find out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$(".rate-instructors i,.rate-activities i").hover(function(){
  $(this).add($(this).prevAll("i")).removeClass("fa-star").addClass("fa-star-o");
  $(this).nextAll("i").removeClass("fa-star-o").addClass("fa-star");
})
```

**Demo**

```js
$(".rate-instructors i,.rate-activities i").hover(function(){
  $(this).add($(this).prevAll("i")).removeClass("fa-star").addClass("fa-star-o");
  $(this).nextAll("i").removeClass("fa-star-o").addClass("fa-star");
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rate-instructors">
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</div>

<div class="rate-activities">
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot mate!

Comment: @QingFeiDeYi No problem, happy to help